# onHover Paper-card polymer

Tags: hover, polymer

how are you?

I'm working in a web site using polymer and need to do the onHover mouse effect on a paper-card. This is my code:

```
<dom-module id="ingeview-projects">
  <template>
    <style include="app-grid-style">
    paper-card {
        --paper-card-header-color: var(--app-primary-color-light);
        width: 30%;
        min-width: 200px;
        margin: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <ul class="app-grid">
      <li class="item">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[projects]]" as="project" strip-whitespace>
          <paper-card image=[[project.metadata.image_url]] preload animated on-mouseover="onHover" on-mouseout="onUnhover">
            <div class="card-content">
              <h1>[[project.nombre]]</h1>
              [[project.descripcion]]
            </div>
            <shop-button>
              <a aria-label$="[[item.title]] Shop Now" href$="/list/[[item.name]]">Ver Más</a>
            </shop-button>
          </paper-card>
        </template>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </template>
<script>

    class IngeViewProjects extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'ingeview-projects'; }

      onHover(e){
        console.log("E");
        //e.srcElement.classList.remove('hovered');
        e.srcElement.image="../images/Metro.png";
      }

      onUnhover(e){
        e.srcElement.image="../images/MetroBlack.png";
        console.log("A");
        //e.srcElement.classList.add('hovered');
      }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          projects: {
            type: Object,
          },
          user: {
            type: Object,
          }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(IngeViewProjects.is, IngeViewProjects);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

But it doesnt works fine, because when track the mouse inside the card, the hover effect appears and desappears. It seems like the hover effect are detect transition between the image in the card and the other part of the card

Can you tell me how can I fix this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: you could add a debounce for unhover this will make it more smooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

If you use *project.metadata.image_url* to set the image in the first place, try changing that variable.

```
  onHover(e){
    console.log("E");
    this.set('project.metadata.image_url', '../images/Metro.png';
  }
```

I would otherwise recommend using css to change images, instead of setting that in code.

```
  paper-card {
    // other stylings
    --paper-card-header-image: "../images/MetroBlack.png";
  }

  paper-card:hover {
    --paper-card-header-image: "../images/Metro.png"
  }
```